# pChart, how to set margin between axis name or axis label?

Tags: php, pchart

My graph result like below, I need to space between axis name or axis label,
here need some space margin between "month", and x-axis labels and similarly for "clicks" and y-axis labels.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just remove the axis label and draw it with [drawText](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.draw.text.html) and align the text using `TEXT_ALIGN_TOPMIDDLE` and the coordinates from the graph area.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find line no. 2344 in `pDraw.class.php` and add value in pixels you want to have as a margin between axis value and the description to the end of the line:

```
$TxtLeft = $XPos-$OuterTickWidth-2-($Bounds[1]["X"]-$Bounds[0]["X"])
```

Forexample: `$TxtLeft = $XPos-$OuterTickWidth-2-($Bounds[1]["X"]-$Bounds[0]["X"]) - 10;`

This will move the text 10 pixels more to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
    $scaleSettings = array("XMargin"=>10,
                           "YMargin"=>10,
                           "Floating"=>TRUE,
                           "GridR"=>200,
                           "GridG"=>200,
                           "GridB"=>200,
                           "DrawSubTicks"=>TRUE,
                           "CycleBackground"=>TRUE);
    $myPicture->drawScale($scaleSettings);
```

Comment: hey @joe, I need space between (2011-11) and "Month", check my graph x-axis, your code make space between axis line or graph area, that's i don't need :(

Answer (score 0):

I added two parameters ($XAxisTitleMargin and $YAxisTitleMargin). You may pass just like other parameters. The patch is at: https://gist.github.com/hkjeffchan/4b89545f879bcdc9c638

```
$Settings = array('XAxisTitleMargin'=>10, 'YAxisTitleMargin' => 10);
$myPicture->drawScale($Settings);
```